# How to solve this equation using semantic equivlence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi I am trying to workout the solution to this propositional logic formula using the below semantic equivalence formula but I am stuck. Could someone please help me out.

These are the rules

```
A ∧ A ≡ A, A ∨ A ≡ A                                         idempotence
A ∧ B ≡ B ∧ A, A ∨ B ≡ B ∨ A                                 commutativity
A ∧ (B ∧ C ) ≡ (A ∧ B) ∧ C , A ∨ (B ∨ C ) ≡ (A ∨ B) ∨ C      associativity
A ∧ (A ∨ B) ≡ A, A ∨ (A ∧ B) ≡ A                             absorption
A ∧ (B ∨ C ) ≡ (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ C )                            distributivity
A ∨ (B ∧ C ) ≡ (A ∨ B) ∧ (A ∨ C )                            distributivity
A ∧ (¬A) ≡ false, A ∨ (¬A) ≡ true                            negation
¬(¬A) ≡ A                                                    double negation
¬(A ∧ B) ≡ (¬A) ∨ (¬B), ¬(A ∨ B) ≡ (¬A) ∧ (¬B)               de Morgan
A ⇒ B ≡ (¬A) ∨ B                                             implication
A ⇔ B ≡ (A ⇒ B) ∧ (B ⇒ A)                                  bi-implication
```

Here is the formula I am trying to workout

```
(p∧q) ⇒ r |= (p⇒ r) v (q⇒r)
```

So far I have done

implication to get

```
¬(p∧q) V r
```

de morgan

```
(¬p v ¬q) v r
```

this is where I am stuck

Comment: $r \lor r \equiv r$. Thus, the last formula is : $(\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \lor (r \lor r)$.

Comment: So Idempotence then I should use associativity?

Comment: @user5647516 Yes, then implication equivalence.